# Excel - How do I convert negative seconds into negative minutes

Tags: microsoft-excel

How do I convert negative seconds (eg. -10) into minutes in the next cell (eg -00:00:10) ?

Comment: Do you mean convert seconds into minutes (-12 seconds is -⅕ minutes), or do you mean convert a number of seconds into an Excel date/time value? What makes you think Excel even supports _negative_ date/time values? Can you type `-00:00:10` directly?)

Comment: Wait, do you want to convert the seconds or minutes? Your title says different to the post, and your example in the post shows seconds and not minutes...

Comment: Do you just want to display some text that you can visually interpret to mean a time, or do you want a time value that Excel can use in time calculations?

Answer (score 0):

If the value is in A1:

```
=IF(A1<0,TEXT(1-A1/24/60/60,"-HH:mm:ss"),TEXT(A1/24/60/60,"HH:mm:ss"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Your question is unclear, you ask for minutes yet it shows it as seconds

As such, I'll keep it with seconds, it's easily updatable to minutes

I would use this

```
=TEXT("-00:00:"&A1*-1,"HH:mm:ss")
```

However, this is only for show as it's a string, I suspect Excel won't like it if you try to use it as a date object

[image]